# Incorrect vertical line spacing after changing font size in table

Tags: tables, fontsize, line-spacing

I would like to change the font size of a parragraph in a table cell. If I do not put \par at the end of the parragraph it does not do the correct line spacing. However, if I put it, I get an anoying white line at the bottom of the cell.

Here is an example with no "\par"

```
\begin{tabular}{m{0.50\textwidth}c}
\emph{Head 1}&\emph{Head 2} \\ \hline
{\footnotesize Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    bla bla bla bla bla.} & C\\
{\footnotesize Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    bla bla bla bla bla.}&C\\ 
{\footnotesize Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    bla bla bla bla bla.}&A\\
\end{tabular}
```

... the result with incorrect linespacing

[image: Table cells with incorrect linespacing]

... the result with the anoying bottom line that prevents the second column to be vertically centered or results in an too large vertical space before the last \hline

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please always post complete documents, but here just remove the `{...}` around your text and just have

```
\footnotesize
```

or simpler just have text in the table and use

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize}m{0.50\textwidth}c}
```

to specify the size as part of the column specification.